# Why are the bottoms of these images lining up?

Tags: html, css

I would like to know why the bottom of these images are lined up across the row of cells? The details are in the code snippet below:

```css
.item {
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}

.row {
    margin: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border: solid orange 2px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.row div {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: table-cell;
    border: solid blue 2px;
    width: 16.666%
}

.row a {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    border:solid red 2px;
    display:block;
}

.row img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="row">
        <div><a class="item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff" /><span>Applied Panel - Base Left Side</span></a></div>
        <div><a class="item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff" /><span>Applied Panel - Base Right Side</span></a></div>
        <div><a class="item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x300/000/fff" /><span>Base - 3 Drawer Stack w-Applied Door</span></a></div>
        <div><a class="item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x600/000/fff" /><span>Base - 3 Drawer Stack</span></a></div>
        <div><a class="item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff" /><span>Base - 4 Drawer Stack w-Applied Door</span></a></div>
        <div><a class="item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff" /><span>Base - 4 Drawer Stack</span></a></div>
    </div>
```

I appreciate this behavior. I would like to keep it. I would really like to understand it, and I need the red box (".row a") to vertically stretch the whole length of it's parent div.

Comment: This is base-line alignment at play: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/17/css-baseline-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly/

Comment: Thanks for the info. I still need to figure out how can i get the red bordered anchor (".row a") to fill the available space.

Comment: I don't think it can be done without losing the base-line alignment you like.  if you set the `a` tags to say `height:300px;` you'll see why.  however the table cells are all the same height, maybe style them around your embedded controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to make the `<a>` cover the entire height/width space of the `<div>`, but your `<div>` has no exact height set it will reflect the height of each individual image within it, and since you CANNOT nest a DIV tag inside an A tag. This would be my suggestion.

**Remove the extra** `<div>` **that you have in front of each** `<a>` **tag.**

```
<div class="row">
   <a class="item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff" /><span>Applied Panel - Base Left Side</span></a>
    <a class="item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff" /><span>Applied Panel - Base Right Side</span></a>
    <a class="item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x300/000/fff" /><span>Base - 3 Drawer Stack w-Applied Door</span></a>
    <a class="item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/300x600/000/fff" /><span>Base - 3 Drawer Stack</span></a>
    <a class="item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff" /><span>Base - 4 Drawer Stack w-Applied Door</span></a>
   <a class="item"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff" /><span>Base - 4 Drawer Stack</span></a>
</div>
```

**Then correct the CSS so that the** `<a>` **tag acts like the** `<div>` **you had before.**

```
.item {
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}

.row {
    margin: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    border: solid orange 2px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.row a {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    border:solid red 2px;
    width: 16.666%;
    display: table-cell;
}

.row img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Notice that I removed the `.row div` and merged it with the `.row a`

This should work.

Comment: I just grok'd this table, table-row, table-cell thing. I cut my CSS in half. This is brilliant stuff. Thanks.